# Building a community from the ground up

Tags: halacha, history

Many times, jewish people were forced to leave their cities and rebuild their communities in other places. Jewish life needs a lot of elements to be practiced at full (bread, wine and candles for the shabat, leather for tefilin, metal for the hanukkiah (?), a piece of land for the cemetery (needs to be specific?), etc).

My question is then:

What is the list of resources that I would need to rebuild a jewish community from scratch, given that I already have a sefer torah? And that I have already managed basic needs such as food, water and shelter.

Comment: send someone ahead to start up a yeshiva

Comment: Mikva for women. Comes even before building a synagogue. Jewish education.

Comment: Hi Welcome, First is 10 men?

Comment: Any old people around? They know.